# Resetting select to certain option AngularJs and Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

So I'm trying to reset the select tag to the first option.

I'm using Materialize CSS as the framework for styling.

I've got the relevant following code but it's not working.

**JS inside AngularJS Controller:**

```
angular.element("#typeSelect").val(angular.element("#typeSelect option:first").val());
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id="typeSelect" name="typeSelect" ng-model="type.Types" ng-options="request.Name for type in types| filter:{Active:true}">
  <option value="first" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas on how to get it to select the first option?

Comment: maybe you should use `delete type.Types` or `type.Types = null`. It will reset your ng-model value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call function like this. and call that when you required to reset

```
$scope.resetVal=function(){
  var myTypes=$scope.types;
   $scope.type.Types=myTypes[0];

}


<select id="typeSelect" name="typeSelect" ng-model="type.Types" ng-options="type.someProperty for type in types| filter:{Active:true}">
  <option value="first" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code,how you are calling reset ?

Comment: I've tried doing "type.Types = 'Choose your option'" on my submit button and that doesn't work either. :(

Comment: please make sure to use  $scope.type.Types not only type.Types

Comment: one more thing 'Choose your option' must be one of your types array name, not any arbitary value

Comment: I've put it in as a ng-click directive on the button. And also, I need it to work with the option tag being there without an array holding the "choose your option" string value.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm asking for. It needs to change back to the <option> tag that is there as default. Cheers